# How can I remove duplicate rows from a table but keeping the summation of values of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose there is a table which has several identical rows. I can copy the distinct values by

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO DESTINATIONTABLE FROM SOURCETABLE
```

but if the table has a column named value and for the sake of simplicity its value is 1 for one particular item in that table. Now that row has another 9 duplicates. So the summation of the value column for that particular item is 10. Now I want to remove the 9 duplicates(or copy the distinct value as I mentioned) and for that item now the value should show 10 and not 1. How can this be achieved?

```
item|     value      
----+----------------
  A | 1
  A | 1
  A | 1
  A | 1
  B | 1
  B | 1
```

I want to show this as below

```
item|     value      
----+----------------
  A | 4
  B | 2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly speaking, you can just us a sum and a GROUP BY clause.

Something like:

```
SELECT column1, SUM(column2) AS Count 
FROM SOURCETABLE
GROUP BY column1
```

Here it is in action: [Sum + Group By](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3fda/3)

Since your table probably isn't just two columns of data, here is a slightly more complex example showing how to do this to a larger table: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bdd75/7)

Note that I've selected my rows individually so that I can access the necessary data, rather than using

```
SELECT *
```

And I have achieved this result without the need for selecting data into another table.

**EDIT 2**:

Further to your comments, it sounds like you want to alter the actual data in your table rather than just querying it. There may be a more elegant way to do this, but a simple way use the above query to populate a temporary table, delete the contents of the existing table, then move all the data back. To do this in my existing example:

```
WITH MyQuery AS (
 SELECT name, type, colour, price, SUM(number) AS number
 FROM MyTable
 GROUP BY name, type, colour, price
)
SELECT * INTO MyTable2 FROM MyQuery;

DELETE FROM MyTable;

INSERT INTO MyTable(name, type, colour, price, number) 
SELECT * FROM MyTable2;

DROP TABLE MyTable2;
```

**WARNING**: If youre going to try this, please use a development environment first (i.e one you don't mind breaking!) to ensure it does exactly what you want it to do. It's imperative that your initial query captures *ALL* the data you want.

Here is the SQL Fiddle of this example in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bdd75/29)

Comment: what if I want to add this sum+ group by in that query - select distinct * into desttable from sourcetable, then what should the query look like?

Comment: @AlapanBag By doing what I've put in my answer. Is there a specific reason for selecting this query into a new table called "desttable"? SELECT all the columns you want to use, SUM the specific column you want to count, then GROUP BY the rest of them. This will ahcive the results you have added to your question.

Comment: No specific reason. I found this a lot easier to remove the duplicate rows

Comment: @AlapanBag If you remove the duplicate rows, you wont be able to sum their values. GROUP BY achieves the result you are looking for. Selecting distinct rows effectively ignores the duplicate rows, whereas GROUP BY groups them together and shows distinct rows of data only once, but the data in each row is still available to you.

Comment: Why will you want to delete  duplicate rows ranter than use *Aggregate function* to get result set? @AlapanBag

Comment: @AlapanBag I've added a demonstration showing how you would implement this to a larger table.

Comment: I get your point. But what if I want to delete the duplicate rows and at the same time use the Aggregate function on the value column? Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: @AlapanBag It sounds like you are saying you want to actually edit the data in the table rather than just query it. I have edited my response again to show you a method of doing this. I would warn you though, altering your tables in this way is not especially safe. If this is a persistent issue for you, I'd consider changing how your data is being entered into the database in the first place.

Comment: Thank you @BarryPiccinni ... I used your query in a stored procedure to solve my problem.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `SUM` and `group by`

```
SELECT item,SUM(value) value      
FROM T 
GROUP BY item
```

SQLfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fac26/1

**[Results]**:

```
| item | value |
|------|-------|
|    A |     4 |
|    B |     2 |
```